# Django, url and forms: what is the point in sending parameters in url?

Tags: regex, django, url

A question I have been asking myself for a long time: what is the advantage to send parameters in Django `urls` instead of using `forms`, except when you want to share some url with someone?

For instance, to me, `path('stuff/<int:expected_value>', views.my_stuff)` will be equivalent to

```
<form method='post' action="{% url 'do_stuff' %}" id='{{ stuff.pk }}'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="some_value" value="{{ object.some_value }}">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

`urls` would always look clean that way, much more simple for the one coding as for the user checking it in the address bar (in my very own opinion of course).

Maybe I just lack some obious knowledge, so please enlighten me!

Comment: By encoding data in a URL, you can for example share the url. For example if I send a URL with `somemagazine.com/some-article`, then you do not need to search `some-article` in a form, you immediately have access to that article.

Comment: although Django and HTML have the concept of a "form", the two are not perfectly in "harmony" all the time, and a HTTP request/response does not know anything about forms. If you hit submit, depending on what the `method` of the form is, you encode the data as an URL query, or in the header of the HTTP request.